# Transferring the scroll gesture form UITableView to UIPanGestureRecogniser

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UITableVIew `tv` that fills a UIView `v`. View `v` has a pan gesture added to it.

When the app starts part of `v` is visible and the user interaction with `tv` is disabled, hence no scrolling for the table when panning `v`.

When the user pans `v` up it snaps to the top of screen after certain threshold distance. At that point `tv` user interaction is enabled so that the user can scroll the table.

I want to enable the user to bring `v` back to its initial location when the table `offset` is `0,0` and the user continues scrolling it down, i.e. offset `0,-y`.

How can I achieve this???  How can I transfer the scroll gesture on `tv` to the pan gesture on `v`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not override the `scrollViewDidScroll:` of the `UITableViewDelegate` to intercept the offset change and update the frame of `v` according to the y offset?

Comment: I thought of this but i thought it would require a lot of refactoring for the logic I have already implemented in the pan gesture handle method. I thought if there is a way of simply transfering the gesture over and the recogniser carry on the job that would be great. But if there is not, i will go this rout.

Comment: I have solved my issue using your recommendation. It was quicker than what I expected :) cheers